# cannot insert into database with python

Tags: python, sql-server, sftp, sql-insert

I get error using python 3.8.5

```py
( cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.sftpserverlist(FileName,FileSize) VALUES ("+files[0]+","+str(sizes[0])+")")
```

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "DidosSupply.zip" could not be bound. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW)')

while I am trying call following function and insert into table `dbo.sftpserverlist`.

```
def getfile(sftp):
    FileNames=[]
    FileName = sftp.listdir_attr()   
    for i in FileName:
        FileNames.append(i.filename)

    FileSizes=[]
    FileSize = sftp.listdir_attr()
    for i in FileSize:
        FileSizes.append(i.st_size)

    return FileNames,FileSizes

-----------------------------------------------------------


cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.sftpserverlist(FileName,FileSize) VALUES ("+files[0]+","+str(sizes[0])+")")
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert with Python, by any means, but I think this is the old-school way of doing it (INSERT INTO).  I recently stumbled upon a super-easy, scalable, and controllable, way of pushing data from Python to SQL Server.  Try the sample code and post back if you have additional questions.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

engine = "mssql+pyodbc://your_server_name/your_database_name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"

... dataframe here...

dataframe.to_sql(x, engine, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

dataframe is pretty self explanatory.

x = the name yo uwant your table to be in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Parametrise your query, don't inject the values, which is a *huge* security flaw.

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.sftpserverlist(FileName,FileSize) VALUES (?,?)",files[0],str(sizes[0]))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The reason you were getting the error was because the values you were (insecurely) injecting weren't quoted; thus the value of `files[0]` (which in this case had the value `"DidosSupply.zip"`) was being interpreted as a column's name; which it can't be as you're within a `VALUES` clause with no `FROM`.

*Of course, just wrapping quotes around the value isn't the solution, as quotes can be escaped.*

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!!!! Now I am also trying to add the modified date as a new columns. :/

Comment: If it solves the problem, please do consider marked it as the solution. @Sangita . Thanks!